# How to prevent quickly from replacing Exec=.* in the .desktop file?

Tags: application-development, quickly, packaging, quicklists, .desktop

I'm still trying to make Quicklists work and found the problem:
Quickly creates `debian/rules` with

```
sed -i 's|Exec=.*|Exec=/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/wakeonplan/bin/wakeonplan|' debian/wakeonplan/usr/share/applications/extras-wakeonplan.desktop; \
```

How do I stop it from doing so to use a static quicklist with CLI options?

Comment: It should be `Exec=[^ ]*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've hit [a bug in Quickly](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/quickly/+bug/1021675).

As a workaround, you can do the following:

1. Open a terminal
2. Run `quickly package --extras`
3. Edit the `rules` file in the `debian` folder of your project and fix that sed line
4. Now run: `debuild -S`
5. And finally run: `dput ppa:yourusername/ppa ../projectname_*_source.changes`

### Troubleshooting

If you are getting signature errors, ensure you've added the following at the end of the `~/.bashrc file`:

```
export DEBFULLNAME='Your name'
export DEBEMAIL='your.email@example.com'
```

Note that:

- The values of `DEBFULLNAME` and `DEBEMAIL` should match those of your GPG key.
- You'll need to restart the terminal for the changes to have effect, or alternatively run `source ~/.bashrc` to reload the file
- You should check that the `debian/changelog` file has got a valid e-mail that matches `DEBFULLNAME` and `DEBEMAIL` too
- You might need to update the version number in the `debian/changelog` file. In any case, ensure that there is no `-public` suffix, or anything else with `-`